# Departure time vs Visa end time

Tags: visas, singapore, vftf

I will be visiting Singapore on a 96 hour visa and flight departure is at 95th hour.
So I am wondering if my flight gets delayed then does it mean that I am breaching visa timeline?

Although I believe visa timeline is for getting Emigration timestamp but I am just wondering if visa officer might see this as a risk? and should I book an earlier flight which departs after 90 hours.

Comment: How many flights a day are there? What if your flight is cancelled altogether or delay is 24h+?

Comment: "Should I book an earlier flight which departs after 90 hours?" If you have the choice, never run things 'up to the wire'.

Comment: 95th hour is cutting very close. If it was me, I would reschedule the flight or get a proper visa (1 week via travel agent, or within hours if you know a PR/Citizen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To amplify the comments: yes, this is a significant risk. If the outbound flight is delayed, you may not be able to pass Singapore exit immigration before your visa term expires. If the outbound flight is cancelled, and there's no outbound light to your destination the same day, things could get thoroughly unpleasant. Here, you're risking an overstay, which will not look good if you seek to travel to Singapore in the future. If Singapore shares its immigration data with any other country, you may find that country also looking askance at a visa application from you.

Thus, the consistent advice from this webpage will be **schedule an earlier departing flight**. If there are multiple flights from Singapore to your destination, a few hours' difference might be enough cushion. If there is only one flight per day, choose a departure flight at least one day in advance of your visa termination.

How large a cushion you choose will depend on the severity of the consequences if something goes wrong (e.g. delayed or canceled flight) and you miss the visa deadline. Here's an example: my wife and I took a boat trip to Antarctica a few years ago. We had a multi-stop itinerary just to get to the departure port, Ushuaia, Argentina. Missing the boat departure would have been unfixable.  Thus, I scheduled to arrive in Ushuaia **two days** before the boat was to depart. This is an extreme example, but if we'd missed the boat, we would have both missed the trip itself and we would have lost the significant paid-in-advance cost.

Comment: You just have to clear exit immigration. After that Singapore doesn't care much. You can stay airside till next flight. Singapore actually allow to stay airside as much as you want (reasonable limitations apply, but 24h should not be an issue.).

Comment: @AnishSheela I agree that clearing Singapore exit immigration is the key. The problem is that the OP may not be permitted to even approach exit immigration if the flight is significantly delayed or cancelled; the OP may not even have a boarding pass for the flight. If the OP doesn't clear exit immigration on time, it's very likely they won't be getting another Singapore visa. There are many ways this could go off the rails.

Comment: I can confirm that post-exit immigration area is open overnight. I have personally checked in 8 hours before. To checkout the airport is a perfectly valid explanation for Singapore.

Comment: @AnishSheela Thanks, I've deleted the closed overnight part of my comment. I think the rest remains valid.

Comment: Yeah, personally, I wouldn't take this risk. Singapore immigration is very friendly, till you have a problem. Then behavior will go south very quickly. :)

Comment: Thanks both. There are many flights form Singapore to India everyday. I have rescheduled my flight to 10 hours before. So hopefully enough cushion.